# Variable assignments in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Which one is the best practice in JavaScript? and Why ?

1>

a) `var object = this.table.toJSON();`

or

b)

```
var object = {};
object = this.table.toJSON();
```

2>

a)

```
var keySelected = "";
```

or

b) `var keySelected = null;`

Comment: all, depends what is your need

Comment: The examples in (2) don't do the same thing.

Comment: @一二三, Many people think they do, which is why the question is here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In example `1B`, setting the `object` to `{}` is pointless, as you are just overwriting its value anyway.  Use `1A` instead.

For `2`, don't use an empty string to mean `null` unless you really want an empty string (such as when you will be concatenating strings to it in a loop).  In general, use `null` for `null`, because that is what it is for.  You can also just use `var keySelected`, and its value will be `undefined`.